# Resizable Sidebar in Svelte. Mouse and sidebar width don't stay in sync

Tags: javascript, html, css, svelte, drag

Having a minimal `Resizable Sidebar` example.

While it works, I would like that the `mouse location` and the `drag handle` stay visually in sync, which is not the case. See attached gif, the mouse moves faster then the sidebar is scaled:
[image]

The code in question (see [Svelte Repl](https://svelte.dev/repl/a23cc6e1be24441c919ea9cc6c6d93c5?version=4.2.0) - *might be a improved/fixed version*):

- `App.svelte`

```
<script>
    import { onDrag } from './dragMe';
    let width = 58;
    let resizeWidth = width;
    let debugDelta;
</script>

    <div style="display: flex;">
        <div style="background-color:red;
                                width:{resizeWidth}px;" >1</div>
                
        <div 
            role="separator"
          aria-orientation="vertical"
            style="background-color:gray; 
                         width:4px;
                         cursor: col-resize;" 
            use:onDrag={{orientation:'vertical'}}
            on:drag={({ detail: delta }) => {resizeWidth = width + delta; debugDelta=delta;}}
            on:dragEnd={() => (width = resizeWidth)}
            > </div>
        
        <div style="background-color:blue;">2</div>
    </div>
```

- `dragMe.js`

```
/** @type {import('svelte/action').Action}  */
export const onDrag = (node, params) => {
  let dragStart = null;

  const attr = params.orientation === 'vertical' ? 'screenX' : 'screenY';

  const mouseDownAction = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    node.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('dragStart', { detail: 'hello' }));
    dragStart = e[attr];
  };
  const mouseMoveAction = (e) => {
    if (dragStart != null) {
      const delta = e[attr] - dragStart;
      node.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('drag', { detail: delta }));
    }
  };
  const mouseUpAction = () => {
    dragStart = null;
    node.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('dragEnd', { detail: 'hello' }));
  };

  node.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDownAction);
  document.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMoveAction);
  document.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUpAction);

  return {
    destroy() {
      node.removeEventListener('mousedown', mouseDownAction);
      document.removeEventListener('mousemove', mouseMoveAction);
      document.removeEventListener('mouseup', mouseUpAction);
    }
  };
};
```

Anyone know what am I missing ?

Comment: Please include all relevant code **in the question**. Links rot and questions should be fully self-contained.

Comment: You are right, added the code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is present probably because of how flex containers work.  Instead of assigning a 100% width to the second DIV, use `flex: 1`.  It will work appropriately.

I don't have an explanation for this.  If any smarter person would like to volunteer one, I am all ears.

Comment: Thanks that fixes the example! In my real app it improves the behavior a lot as well, although I multiply the delta with `1.1` since there is still a slight deviation there.